# Windows Phone 7 Photo Chooser with Camera Option

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm currently using a "Camera Chooser" on my app, but want my user to be able to select from either their current library of photos AND still have the option to take a picture immediately.

The "Photo Chooser" provided by Microsoft Doesn't have the option to select the camera instead, whereas if you go to SMS on a windows phone and tap "Attach" it launches a photo chooser but it has an app bar with the option to grab a photo from the camera.

Is this possible with the developer SDK or has Microsoft made it so only they can do this?

Thanks
Danny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and set the [ShowCamera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.showcamera%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property to true.