# Simple photo taking, storing, loading on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application I have a data entry view which I'd also like to give the user the option to store a photograph. Currently, using the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx, I've got a button which lets me take the photo, and can display it back properly at the bottom of the view.

However, I'd like this photo to be saved as part of the record. I thought it would be simple to save the location of the file as a string(I can access this by using PhotoResultObject.OriginalFileName), then display the photo again by using a URI like in my code here. This is inside the cameraCaptureTask_Completed method, e is a PhotoResult object.

```
    string imageLoc = e.OriginalFileName;
    Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageLoc, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
    myImage.Source = bmp;
```

However, this gives me an Argument exception, or various other exceptions when I move things around. I'm pretty new to c# so I'm really certain what's going on.

I reckon it's something to do with trying to access the photo straight from the phone memory, but I haven't found any other clear ways to store photos which will stay accessible inside the app.

Any tips on where I'm going wrong or how to accomplish my aim would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696552/windows-phone-7-photo-chooser-with-camera-option
here is the solution

Comment: I don't want the user to be given the opportunity to choose a photo, I just want the photo taken to be saved, displayed, and it's location stored.

Comment: Ohh my mistake.
have to tried this because it works.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx